# How to import csv in KNIME and ignore the quote marks

Tags: csv, import, knime

I have a csv file with data like this:

`"Column1; Column2; Column3"
"ValueA; ValueB; ValueC"
"ValueD; ValueE; ValueF"`

When i import it using the 'CSV Reader'-Node it interprets the quote marks as content. 
I need the data to be imported without the quotation marks though (formatting it after that does not feel like a clean way of doing this and the node interprets the data formats wrong).

The setting of the node is as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJC1k.png

How can i deal with this?

Comment: I would not call that as CSV file, though you can read it with `Line Reader` and do the stripping and splitting on that. I think it is easier to use the `CSV`Reader` as you do and do the postprocessing on the first and last column only.

Answer (score 0):

In configuration dialog add " as Quote Char.

Comment: This does not work because when i do it the whole line gets interpreted as one value (one big string).

Comment: I see now. Sry. Don't think there is clean way of reading files formatted like this into KNIME. But after CSV Reader simply use [Cell Splitter](https://kni.me/n/t8H2CJ_kkOGFnxyV) and you will get your columns.

Comment: Yes, i did the workaround now. I saw no better way.

Answer (score 0):

@FlipForties Hi,

As a heavy KNIME user I would recommend trying to load your data via the File Reader node instead. It's much more flexible than the CSV Read node and you should be able to load your data as is without issues. I made a test data-set and it looks ok upon load. See screen shot below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t6rY.png)